# Compare Highest Income Visitor from Two Columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table with certain columns.

```
**table_1**
device_uuid          
visited_store_1      
visited_store_2     
income             
parent
```

Im suppose to find which one of the stores has the highest top 10 income people. 
I can think of finding the top 10 individually but how will I join it in a query to compare it and return a single store result?

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: MySQL but the question doesnt mention any particular one to use.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? Which colnum represent   `income people`

Comment: Sadly its just a picture that was given to me with https://drive.google.com/open?id=1O4MiXiovZqVv-NTXI3bhiKpCw8DqScPQ

Comment: Ok what do you mean  `join it in a query to compare it and return a single store result?`

Comment: The way I was thinking is that I could have found top ten for store 1 then store 2 and try to compare which one had the highest income people

Comment: There are two store columns.  I'm confused.

Answer (score 0):

```
with dat as (
select 
    'store1' name, 
    avg(income) avg_income, 
    sum(income) total_income
from table_1
where visited_store_1 = TRUE
order by income desc
limit 10

union all 

select 
    'store2' name, 
    avg(income) avg_income, 
    sum(income) total_income
from table_1
where visited_store_2 = TRUE
order by income desc
limit 10
)

select name
from dat
order by avg_income desc
limit 1
```

I just don't know what metric to use for "Top 10 income people"; I used average for the final query, but the subqueries have both.

Comment: I don't think this will work exactly as written since the `limit 10`s won't be applied before the `sum`/`avg`.

Answer (score 0):

create table #temp (visitor int)
insert into #temp
select max(visitor) as visitor from shop1 
union 
select max(visitor) as visitor from shop2

select max(visitor) from #temp

Answer (score 0):

select case when (max(a.visitor)>=max(b.visitor)) then max(a.visitor) else max(b.visitor) end  from shop1 a,shop2 b

Comment: I think using a case would do the job here. They only I can find out is by getting the answers back later. Much appreciate it